# Preventing and then resuming default action

Tags: javascript

I have a table with a delete option against each row, which is a link that redirects to the delete function. I want to add a modal now, with two options- cancel and delete. I want to stop the delete link from performing its default action, and open the modal instead, and then I want the the default action of the delete link to be resumed if I click on the delete button in the modal. I just started learning javascript and any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the javascript code snippet:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('open-modal');
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);

function openModal(e){
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

This is the delete link:

```py
<a id="open-modal" href="{{ url_for('delete_product', product_id=product.id) }}">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should save your event somewhere else by using the event.constructor prototype
function. After that you perform its default action by using the dispatchEvent
method on your saved event. The example below works fine.

```
<html>
<a id="open-modal" href="{{ url_for('delete_product', product_id=product.id) }}">Delete</a>
<button onclick="executeSavedEvent()"> Execute Saved Event</button>
<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    var modalBtn = document.getElementById('open-modal');
    modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);

    var savedEvent;

    function openModal(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        savedEvent = new e.constructor(e.type);

        modal.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function executeSavedEvent() {
        modalBtn.dispatchEvent(savedEvent);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I don't really want a new button. Also, the default action of the delete link is still being carried out.

Comment: You should put the executeSavedEvent function call on the delete button you mentioned.
This was just an example to demonstrate its functionality